# Locomotive cms - create custom field type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locomotivecms

There are multiple field types in Locomotive CMS engine:
http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/content-types/reference

However, I would like to create my own field type. Is there any easy procedure to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but no, there isn't.

LocomotiveCMS supports all the core field types you would expect: string, text, integer, float, date, datetime, file, and boolean, plus some other non-essential field types. So, just about any data can be accommodated, though you might need to use multiple fields.

If you want to modify how a field is displayed, custom Liquid tags or filters can be an easy solution.

If you need custom validation for the field type, you'll have to create a create a Rails model for the content type and then make a droplet of the content type for LocomotiveCMS, like done here: https://github.com/locomotivecms/mini_app. This is a little harder.

What kind of field type are you looking to make?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give a try!
I am looking for a field type, that has a custom view with file multiupload.